# Libreoffice Presenter Console in single window

Tags: multiple-monitors, libreoffice

I want to see what Presenter Console looks like while I design my slide-notes in Libreoffice Impress for my talks. I'm working on a single-monitor system but Presenter Console can only be enabled (Slide Show → Settings) when a second monitor is present.

Is there a way to show (only) Presenter Console on a single monitor?

Comment: Here is a link to a easy solution using a macro which allows to toggle between presenter screen and normal screen before starting the presentation: [https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/64534/feature-request-add-show-presenter-view-in-impress/](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/64534/feature-request-add-show-presenter-view-in-impress/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you mean the “Presenter Console”.

Yes, use `Open Expert Configuration` via Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Advanced.
Search for StartAlways.
You should get a node org.openoffice.Office.PresenterScreen with line Presenter. Double-click that line to toggle the boolean value to true.

But still I do not know, how to share not a whole window.

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking for a way to do the same thing.

While still quite clumsy, this is the simplest method I have found so far:

You will need to install Xephyr (which lets you start an X server in a window) and a light window manager like xfwm4:

```
sudo apt-get install Xephyr xfwm4
```

Then start up Xephyr with two screens:

```
Xephyr +xinerama -screen 800x600 -origin 800x0 -screen 800x600 :1 &
```

Then start a window manager on the new server:

```
DISPLAY=:1 xfwm4 &
```

Then start impress:

```
DISPLAY=:1 libreoffice --impress &
```

I wish it weren't this complicated. Having an option in Impress to view the console on a single monitor setup would be very useful when practicing presentations.

Comment: That this is the solution is pretty insane.

Answer (score 2):

I found a macro on the Libreoffice community site that lets one manually toggle presenter mode without a second screen.

[Add show presenter view in Impress | Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/64534/feature-request-add-show-presenter-view-in-impress/)

Not the cleanest solution, but seems nicer than launching a second x-server.

Comment: Would be nice to have easy steps to install that.